# testing significance among distributions

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions

I have three probability distributions. How can I test if they are statistically different from one another? Alternatively, how could I test if one distribution is different than the other two combined?

Here is an example of what the distributions look like:

[image: distributions]